# Firebase LoginWithCustomToken throws error

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I am creating firebase custom token with jsonwebtoken in nodejs and once token created and passing to the firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token) return error message says as below

**the custom token format is incorrect. please check the documentation.**

private_key:"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n*****\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

stored the private_key in fb-private-secret.key file

**Note**:*-- along with \n as I have got in ServiceAccountKey.json file from the firebase.*

```
**Sample code:-**

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const fb_private_key = fs.readFileSync('./fb-private-secret.key').toString().replace(/\\n/gm, '\n');

in Nodejs express :-

const token = jwt.sign({
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/****",
  "sub": user.uid,
  "aud": "banded-totality-****",
  "iat": new Date().getTime(),
  "exp": new Date().getTime()+(60*60*24*5)*1000,
  "uid":user.uid
},fb_private_key,{header:{kid:'#####' }, algorithm:'RS256' });

In Reactjs Front-End:-
//token which i get from the server.
const {user} = await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token);
At the above line (signInWithCustomToken) error comes says
the custom token format is incorrect. please check the documentation.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To sign in with a custom token, must be generated with the correct properties. Specifically:

```
alg: "RS256"
aud: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit"
```

**Update**

**Admin SDK solution:**

```js
const  admin = require('firebase-admin');
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials)
});

// example of claims
const additionalClaims = {
    premium: true
}

admin.auth().createCustomToken("user_id_goes_here", additionalClaims)
.then((customToken )=> {
    console.log(customToken);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Yes, I gone through the doumentatioin but the URL in the aut throws 404.

Comment: I tried the same in previous few request but same error message thrown.

Comment: if you have the admin-sdk, you can generate the user token directly, I suspect the issue might be related to the fb_private_key

Comment: using admin-sdk i created token but expires in 1 hour. If I set exp time in the custom token creation it says that exp is a reserved keyword. To increase the expire time i used the steps which I have shared in the code.

Comment: It is expected to expire. When the user logs in with the custom token, you also gain a refresh token, when it expires, you request a new ID token from the project identity toolkit using the refresh token. Firebase Auth should handle this passively,

Comment: Thanks. I used refresh token and generated new token to be stored and sent back to the backend to verify the request. Now it works.

Comment: Awesome, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, it'll help me out too

Comment: From the server end which I shared the code could not work. I refreshed the token from the front-end in certain time interval. Only I did that but for this post to create custom token and login by that token could not work. So, Can not mark as answered. But I would appreciate that in this world only you came to help me. Thanks a lot. BTW- I am still waiting someone who can post the answer for this post then I would accept the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer and evaluated the code with the correct changes per the documentation and was able to generate a working auth token which you can decode here: https://jwt.io/

Comment: For simplicity sake, I do suggest using the admin sdk, there seems to be some issues with the rest API and custom jwt's that I will need to collaborate with fellow firebaser users - I'll update if I find a solution